# Print matched pattern with AWK

Tags: regex, unix, awk

For example i have this data:

```
/home/test/dat1.txt
/home/test/dat2.txt
/home/test/test1/dat3.txt
/home/test/test2/dat4.txt
/home/test/test3/test4/dat5.txt
```

I need to print only the name and extension, that output should be:

```
dat1.txt
dat2.txt
dat3.txt
dat4.txt
dat5.txt
```

I need to use the awk command... anyone can help?

I use this regular expression: `'/\/*\.txt/{print ???}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use `awk`, you do not need a regex for this purpose. 
You can just tell `awk` to print the last field, using a field separator of `/`.

```
awk -F'/' '{print $NF}' Input.txt
```

As hd1's comment already noted, `NF` is the number of fields on the current input record (in this case line). Since `awk` starts indexing fields at `$1`, `$NF` gives you the last field.

Comment: Would you like to explain me what is NF?
And how ever, this will give me all doc files, not only .txt..

Comment: From the gawk manpage -- `NF          The number of fields in the current input record.`

Comment: @JovanMeshkov, Updated for completeness.

Comment: Thank you, i separated the .txt with regex, before print! I will mark as accepted, after the minutes delay!

Comment: Otherwise you can do `awk -F'/' '$NF ~ /\.txt$/ {print $NF}' Input.txt` which only selects the `.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this short `awk`

```
awk -F/ '$0=$NF' Input.txt
```

If you need empty line use

```
awk -F/ '{$0=$NF}1' Input.txt
```